Using the dirac delta within a conditional probability context, using a continuous random variable
I am having trouble understanding the following equation:
$$P(t|v) = \int dn\delta(t-vn)P(n)$$
"t" is the fluorescent intensity of all molecules, "v" is the fluorescent intensity of a single molecule, and
"n" is the total number of molecules. Therefore, t = vn. "n" is also the integration variable. The integral (as written in the paper) doesn't have any limits.
I understand that the integral of the dirac delta evaluates to 1 when t=vn in this case. But seeing as how this integral equals 1, why even include it in the first place? Doesn't this simply equate to P(t|v) = P(n) ? I dont why we include the dirac delta, as it just ends up multiplying P(n) by 1.
I hope this makes sense.. Thank you for your help.

Hi Michael, it is not clear to me with the way it is written, where the delta function is and what the integration variable is and what the integration limits are. You can use $\text{$\delta(y)$}$ which will render as $\delta(y)$. For more Mathjax help, refer to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Terribly sorry, I have edited my original post. Hopefully it is more clear now.
"n" is the integration variable. The integral (as written in the paper) does not have any limits that I can see..

"Sifting" property of Dirac Delta works only when the integration is over $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$. Assuming that, the sifting property makes the RHS equal to $\frac{1}{|v|} P(\frac{t}{v})$. Scaling propery: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Scaling_and_symmetry and sifting property: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Translation

What is the paper?

Here is the paper:
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/16648159/

The Dirac Delta is NOT a function and the symbol $\int$ is NOT an integral.  The Dirac Delta is a linear functional that maps smooth functions $\phi$ as $\langle \delta,\phi\rangle =\phi(0)$.  As already commented the value of the linear functional in the OP is simply $\frac1{|v|}P(t/v))$.  And that is that.

It is worth noting that the Dirac delta function is particularly useful to write down the relation between the continuous density $P(n)$ and the discrete probabilities $p_{i}$:
$$P(n) = \sum_{i} p_{i} \space \delta(n-n_{i})$$
That is formula is correct, can be checked by evaluating $< n >$. The outcome is $<n> = \sum_{i} p_{i}n_{i}$, which is obviously correct. Similarly we can write an expression for the density $\rho(t)$:
$$\rho(t) = \sum_{i} p_{i} \space \delta(t - vn_{i})$$
The relation between these two densities $P(n)$ and $\rho(t)$ indeed takes the form:
$$\rho(t) = \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} dn \space \delta(t - nv) \space P(n)$$
This can be verified by substituting the expression derived for $P(n)$ in the RHS, performing the integration over $n$ and using the properties of the Dirac delta function.
